# What's the diference between 'normal' Python Classes and Pydantic Classes?

Tags: python, class, pydantic

I would like to know the difference between classes built normally in python and those built with the Pydantic lib, for example:

eg normal;

```
   class Node:
        def __init__(self, chave=None, esquerda=None, direita=None):
            self.chave = chave
            self.esquerda = esquerda
            self.direita = direita
```

eg pydantic;

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name = 'John Doe'
    signup_ts: Optional[datetime] = None
    friends: List[int] = []
```

Comment: let's just say `self.id = 'hello'` is possible with the first one, but will raise an error with the second.

Comment: thank you Ahmed, can u tell me why?

Comment: Because of `id: int` in the second class definition.  That means id must be an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few main differences.
Firstly, purpose. Pydantic models are designed to:

> *Data validation and settings management using python type annotations.
> pydantic enforces type hints at runtime, and provides user friendly errors when data is invalid.*

When you use type annotations you receive a lot of [validators](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) and some useful methods out of the box.

As Ahmed and John says, in your example you can't assign `“hello”` to `id` in BaseModel (pydantic) because you type `id` as an int. But you can pass a string `“1”` (must be a numerical, not float) and it will be mapped to `int`. In this case:

> *pydantic uses int(v) to coerce types to an int; see this warning on loss of information during data conversion*

Also Pydantic models allows you to use many more [types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/) than standard python types, like [urls](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#urls) and much more. It means that you can easily validate more data types.

You can easily create [complex models](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#recursive-models) using [composition](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/#composition-in-python).

Pydantic has some kind of integration with orms: [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances)

There are a lot of other features, much more than I can describe in a single answer. I strongly recommend reading the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), it is very clear and useful.

The pydantic models are very useful for example in building microservices where you can share your interfaces as pydantic models. Also all models can easily generate the json schema. See: [Schema](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/), [exporting models](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/).

Pydantic is also a big part of a growing in popularity python web framework [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).

Comment: Thank you Jace, it was very enlightening

Answer (score 0):

The main differences are:

- `pydantic` ensures that the data you work with conforms to the specified structure and data types,
- `pydantic` performs runtime type checking. The library will automatically validate the fields when creating an instance of the model and convert input data to the declared types if possible, or
  raise an error if it cannot.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: float
    is_in_stock: bool

item = Item(name='Widget', price=25.99, is_in_stock=True)
```

If you initialize a class like this

```py
item = Item(name=12, price=25.99, is_in_stock=True)
```

it will raise an error because `name` should be a `string`, not a number.

In normal `python` class, you will not get such error.